# www-data and permissions

Tags: permissions

Well, I have a problem with permissions.

- If I create folder with Php, owner is `www-data`
- If I create folder with Ftp, owner is `storage_01`

For example:

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data   www-data  4096 May 14 05:13 ixq4mz
drwxrwsr-x 3 storage_01 www-data  4096 May 13 16:40 mhpj38
drwxrwsr-x 2 storage_01 www-data  4096 May 12 12:32 zk22xa
```

I'm like to delete folders and files from FTP (I use proftpd), when I try to delete, i get 550 error.

I understand `storage_01` is different user and not owner, but how can I allow `storage_01` to delete `www-data` owned folders?

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to your problem.

you can just chmod and give permissions to every one and thus the user of ftp will be able to delete.

This can be done with

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/Whatever-folder
```

**BUT** this is not recommended since though you a re giving the read write and execute permissions to all other users in your system.

> So What is the optimal solution for your problem?

Easily you can just make the ftp user which is called storage_01 as a member of the www-data group and thus this user will take the permissions of the group.

The syntax is

```
usermod -a -G {group-name} username
```

So in your case

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data storage_01
```

And now the user storage_01 got the group permissions of www-data.

Another thing to take care of to test if you already had a permission for the group.

Another solution but it'll be more complicated is to make another new group which contains both users `www-data` and the `storage_01` and then change ownership of the directories to that group.

Comment: `useradd` creates new users, `usermod` modifies existing ones. Remind me if we have had a conversation about `usermod -G` and `adduser` before.

Comment: User is already on www-data group, i need to restar apache?

Comment: hhh yeah It's right just mistype

Comment: @HidDencum Did you add the storage_01 user to www-data group?

Comment: root@101:/mnt/storage_01# useradd -G www-data storage_01
useradd: user 'storage_01' already exists

Comment: @HidDencum Sorry friend it was typo error of me you should use usermod not useradd so the correct command `sudo usermod -a -G www-data storage_01`

Comment: 550 error continue :(((

Comment: Where you see this error? did you add the user? what is the output of the command `getent group www-data`

Comment: www-data:x:33:storage_01

Comment: Error 550 appear o FTP client

Comment: What is the permission of the files you want to delete? you can get by `ls -l /path-to-file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23753/discussion-between-hid-dencum-and-new-user).

Comment: Contain a folder: drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 May 14 05:46 ixq4mz